# how to fix the issue that engine.table_names() returns nothing, but in fact table exists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been digging into this issue for a long while, although there are many posts about it, but it seems none of them is helpful.

I have this part of code:

```
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:******@10.**.**.**:4406/metrics')
>>> engine.table_names()
[]
>>> metadata
MetaData(bind=None)
>>> metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
>>> metadata
MetaData(bind=None)
>>> engine
Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://root:***@10.**.**.**:4406/metrics)
>>> metadata.sorted_tables
[]
>>> engine.execute('show tables').fetchall()
[(bytearray(b'TableName1'),), (bytearray(b'TableName2'),), (bytearray(b'TableName3'),), (bytearray(b'TableName4'),), (bytearray(b'TableName5'),), (bytearray(b'TableName6'),), (bytearray(b'TableName7'),), (bytearray(b'TableName8'),), (bytearray(b'TableName9'),), (bytearray(b'TableName10'),), (bytearray(b'TableName11'),), (bytearray(b'TableName12'),), (bytearray(b'TableName13'),), (bytearray(b'TableName14'),), (bytearray(b'TableName15'),), (bytearray(b'TableName16'),), (bytearray(b'TableName17'),), (bytearray(b'TableName18'),), (bytearray(b'TableName19'),)]
```

how to make it fixed?

Is it link to sqlconnector?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Add `echo=True` to your `create_engine` call and when you execute `engine.table_names()` does it issue a `SHOW FULL TABLES FROM metrics` query?

Comment: @SuperShoot, here's the output: 


2019-03-29 12:40:33,975 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `metrics`
2019-03-29 12:40:33,975 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
[]

Comment: If you execute the show full tables command yourself through the engine: `engine.execute('SHOW FULL TABLES FROM metrics').fetchall()` is it empty too?

Comment: @SuperShoot, in my post of the question, I've already posted the output of "show tables". It's not empty.

Comment: The point was to mirror the exact same `SHOW FULL TABLES FROM metrics` query that sqla is executing but returning nothing as that is the query SQLAlchemy is using to get the table names, not `SHOW TABLES` which is what you have included in your question. All the best with finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same output "[ ]" when using `engine.table_names()`. To fix that you must provide an "schema" as MetaData() parameter.
Below is a simple function I created for getting a list of the tables of my db:

```
def get_tables(engine, schema):
  metadata = MetaData(schema = schema)
  metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
  tables = []
  for table in metadata.tables:
      table_name = table.replace(f'{schema}.', '')
      tables.append(table_name)
  return tables
```